# Php curl in foreach check status

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, api, curl

How to make a foreach or a loop when checking multidimensional array like ? What am i doing wrong ?

I am trying to get status from BKM with vkn or tckn;

Also i want to insert as 1 if merchant is blacklisted and as 0 if merchant is not blacklisted

I have tried to find answer from a lot of forums but I couldnt get right answer if someone would help that would be great !

```
   $datas = [
      0 => [
        "VKN" => 23112131231,
        "TCKN" => 23232131313
           ],
      1 => [
        "VKN" => 232131232,
        "TCKN" => 231321412421
    ];
```

```
    $insertData = [];
    $basic_auth = base64_encode(Merchant::BKM_USERNAME.':'.Merchant::BKM_PASSWORD);

    foreach ($datas as $key => $value)
    {
      $insertData[$key]["user_id"] = Auth::user()->id;
      $insertData[$key]["vkn"] = $value["VKN"];
      $insertData[$key]["tckn"] = $value["TCKN"];

      $ch[$key] = curl_init();

      curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_URL, Merchant::BKM_TOKEN_URL);
      curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=password");
      curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: */*', 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization: Basic '.$basic_auth));
      curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

      $http_response[$key] = curl_exec($ch[$key]);
      $http_code[$key] = curl_getinfo($ch[$key], CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
      $http_error[$key] = curl_errno($ch[$key]) ? curl_error($ch[$key]) : '';
      curl_close($ch[$key]);

      if($http_code[$key] == 200)
      {
      $decoded[$key] = json_decode($http_response[$key], true);
      $token[$key] = $decoded[$key]['access_token'];
      $taxNo = $value["VKN"] ? $value["VKN"] : '';
      $identityNo = $value["TCKN"] ? $value["TCKN"] : $taxNo;

        if($taxNo) 
        {
         $get_param = '?TaxNo='.$taxNo;
        } else {
         $get_param = '?IdentityNo='.$identityNo;
        }

       $ch[$key] = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_URL, Merchant::BKM_CHECK_URL.$get_param);
       curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: */*', 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization: Basic '.$basic_auth));
       curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

       $http_response2[$key] = curl_exec($ch[$key]);
       $http_code2[$key] = curl_getinfo($ch[$key], CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
       $http_error2[$key] = curl_errno($ch[$key]) ? curl_error($ch) : '';
       curl_close($ch[$key]);
       }
       if($http_code2[$key] == 200) {
                        $decoded2[$key] = json_decode($http_response2[$key], true);
    
                        echo json_encode($decoded2[$key], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
                    } else {
                        echo json_encode($http_error2[$key], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
                    }
                } 
                else {
                    echo json_encode($http_error[$key], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
                    }
            }   
            
     if (isset($request->importAction) && ($request->importAction == 'save_query')) {
                $merchant_status->insert($datas);
            }
```

Comment: What exactly goes wrong when you run this? You didn't really describe the actual problem you're experiencing

Comment: However, it's likely that this code will output multiple individual JSON objects into the response. Are you getting an error in the client about invalid JSON, perhaps? You need to save all the results into a bigger structure (perhaps an array) and then json_encode that whole array _once_ at the end of the script. Outputting separate snippets of JSON doesn't produce a single valid piece of JSON that can be parsed.

Comment: What error you've got?

Comment: This returns internal server or 403 error @ADyson

Comment: Those are two different errors with different causes. Are you saying you sometimes get one error and sometimes the other? There must be some difference between the requests to get each type of error. Can you clarify the circumstances?

Comment: sorry Forget about 500 When I come to if($http_code[$key] == 200) and if($http_code2[$key] == 200) response is 403  i need to pass from this control. After that as a result like 'status' => 1 or 'status' = 0. If It passes the condition i want to insert data like                                                          
           [ 'TCKN'  = 231332132131, 'VKN' = 321312321313, 'status' = 0 or if false 'status' = 1 ] @ADyson

Comment: Ok well clearly 403 is "forbidden" so it simply means you don't have permission to send a request to that URL. Maybe your authentication data is incorrect. It's hard for us to know because we don't know your credentials, and we don't know what format the remote server expects to receive them.

Comment: What do you think about coding process is it correct or there is better way to do it .Maybe additional methods for curl @ADyson

Comment: See again the second sentence of my previous comment.